# I reformatted my computer to a new OS - need to restore files and folders

Tags: restore

I did see on another question that files and folder will automatically start synching.  I want to make sure if I synch the the Ubuntu One folder on my computer with Windows 7 it will download all the material stored on-line and not delete anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you sync folders using Ubuntu One, nothing will be deleted unless you actually mean to delete something. You can sync the Ubuntu One folder safely to Windows 7, without anything being deleted.